# How to find $y$ for this equation?

Tags: calculus

$xdy=(y-\sqrt{x^2 +y^2})dx$

$y(x) =z(x) x$

$dy =zdx+xdz$

$x(zdx+xdz) =(xz-\sqrt{x^2 +x^2 z^2})dx$

...

$xdz =-\sqrt{1^2 +z^2} ×dx$

$\frac {dx} {x} = - \frac {dz}{\sqrt{1^2 +z^2}}$

$ln(x) +C= - ln|z+ \sqrt{1^2 +z^2}|$

...

$x(z+\sqrt{1^2 +z^2}) =C$

$x(\frac{y} {x} + \frac {\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}} {x}) =C$

$y+\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} =C $

Now how to solve it for $y$? And what is $C$ equal to?

Comment: Finding the constant 'C' requires a point on the solution curve.

Comment: It is like in integration, you have a constant $+C$ at the end. (Indefinite integral). You cannot determine it unless you have an initial condition. To solve for $y$, move $y$ to the other side and get $C-y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now continue.

Comment: @GarethMa that doesn't help

Comment: @LeanaK.How does it not help?

Answer (score 1):

$$C-y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$(C-y)^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$y^2-2Cy+C^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$-2Cy+C^2=x^2$$

$$y=\frac{C^2-x^2}{2C}$$

You cannot solve for $C$, as you do not have an initial condition (like in an indefinite integral).

Comment: I need y as a real number

Comment: What... Do you have an initial condition? you cannot solve for $y$ as a value without it... Try to solve $x+y=3$ for $y$.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/rk4Vxy8

Comment: Well, now you have $C$, you can find $y$. You cannot find a value $y$ without the $x$ either. Can you show us your question? Do you know what you're doing/what you're supposed to do?

Comment: I need to get general solution of the equation

Comment: You have the general solution... $y=\frac{C^2-x^2}{2C}$ is the general solution...